# How to open a screen from a class (outside a widget) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

So, I have my lab_widget that has a normal button and it calls a function from another file called not_plugin. I want that every time I click on the button, the function in not_pugin opens a determined screen. This is what I have in not_plugin:

```
Future<dynamic> onClick(String payload) async {
     //Do other things

     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LabMdScreen()));
}
```

But it throws the following error:

> 46:24: Error: The getter 'context' isn't defined for the class 'NotPlugin'.
>
> - 'NotPlugin' is from 'not_plugin.dart'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
>   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyScreen()));

So how can I resolve this?

**UPDATE**

After pass a BuildContext, throws this error in another function:

```dart
Future<void> initLocalNotification() async {
    androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');//here
    iosInitializationSettings = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitializationSettings, iOS: iosInitializationSettings);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onClick());
  }
```

In the last line (onSelectNotification: onClick());)

> error: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Function(String)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a BuildContext to your function:

```
void onClick(String payload, BuildContext context) {
     //Do other things

     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LabMdScreen()));
}
```

Comment: error: The argument type 'Future<dynamic> Function(String, BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic> Function(String)'.

Comment: Why is your function async btw?

Comment: did you pass the context where you call this function and imported material in this class?

Comment: yes, but I have another function which is throwing, I will update the question to you see

Comment: I'm still unable to see where you call the onClick function, can you show where do you call this function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224692/discussion-between-jed1-and-kennedypz).